# Is there a way to use will_paginate on a single record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a basic blogging rails app, is there a way to paginate the bodytext property of an Articles model? I'm using will_paginate to paginate the list of articles, but I'm not sure that I could apply it to the bodytext.

I thought about turning a body text into an array of words in the controller when I'm rendering it, but [will_paginate's wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Troubleshooting) explicitly says not to use it on static arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you want to implement?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - I want a single Article to have its body text paginated across multiple pages. Such that if an Article had a body of 9 paragraphs, it might be split across 3 pages, with 3 paragraphs each, and pagination controls to click back and forth.